# Error in Using YCSB with Gemfire

Tags: benchmarking, ycsb, gemfire

Hii Am Using YCSB for Benchmarking Pivotal Gemfire My Gemfire server is running properly and by using following command am running the benchmarking test.

bin/ycsb load gemfire -P workloads/workloada -p gemfire.serverhost=x.x.x.x -P gemfire-binding/conf/cache.xml -p gemfire.serverport=40404 -s > load.txt

Loading workload...
Starting test.
 0 sec: 0 operations; 
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use client-cache in the cache.xml when ClientCacheFactory is used.
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheCreation.create(CacheCreation.java:316)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheXmlParser.create(CacheXmlParser.java:274)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.loadCacheXml(GemFireCacheImpl.java:3495)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.initializeDeclarativeCache(GemFireCacheImpl.java:926)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.init(GemFireCacheImpl.java:708)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.create(GemFireCacheImpl.java:533)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCacheFactory.basicCreate(ClientCacheFactory.java:207)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCacheFactory.create(ClientCacheFactory.java:161)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.GemFireClient.init(GemFireClient.java:125)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:189)
 0 sec: 0 operations;

Please anybody tell can tell me where am going wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your cache.xml file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cache PUBLIC "-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Cache 7.0//EN" "http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache7_0.dtd">
<cache lock-lease="120" lock-timeout="60" search-timeout="300" is-server="false" copy-on-read="false">
  <!-- Add Region Elements Here -->
 <region name="usertable" refid="PARTITION"/>
</cache>

Comment: this is the cache.xml which is currently used by cacheserver

Comment: please mention the step to setup gemfire for ycsb it vl be very useful to me thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your setup is not clear to me. Do you have an already running cacheserver configured with the above cache.xml that you are trying to connect your ycsb test to? I am not familiar with ycsb but I think this is a gemfire configuration issue regardless. It looks like you are trying to use a client cache in your tests but yet your test configuration cache.xml is not configured as a client cache.

Comment: No i Have started the server using gfsh admin shell by the following command start server --name=server1 --server-port=40405 --server-host=x.x.x.x --cache-xml-file=/home/prashant/YCSB/cache.xml

Comment: Did my answer fix the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your GemFireClient.java you are setting up a client cache with the `ClientCacheFactory` class but the cache.xml that you are giving it for configuration is specifying a `cache` element instead of a `client-cache` element. Try changing your cache.xml to use a `client-cache` similar to the below example. Note that when configuring a client-cache in your cache.xml you will need to use a different DTD than the one used above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE client-cache PUBLIC
    "-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Caching 7.0//EN"
    "http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache7_0.dtd">
<client-cache copy-on-read="false" >
    <region name="usertable" refid="PARTITION"/> 
</client-cache>
```

Comment: @ tom I tried after making above changes in the xml also but it is showing error in starting the server :



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use ClientCacheFactory when the cache.xml uses client-cache.
 at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.ClientCacheCreation.create(ClientCacheCreation.java:189)
 at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheXmlParser.create(CacheXmlParser.java:293)
 at`code`

Comment: Can you show the code for GemFireClient.java and the client's cache.xml (the one you refer to in the ycbs startup line)?

Comment: Gemfire client which am using is here at this link [link]https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/gemfire/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/db/GemFireClient.java

and the client.xml which am using the same which you have mentioned in your ananswer above

Comment: And what is the cache.xml that you are using for the server? The one at /home/prashant/YCSB/cache.xm?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to specify a cache.xml when running the YCSB client. The cache.xml in gemfire-binding/conf folder is meant to be supplied to the GemFire server.